# Can't display bootstrap modal onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a problem to display the bootstrap modal in my react-website. Here is my code:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './restaurant.css';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {IoMdArrowBack} from 'react-icons/io';
import './restaurantMenu.css';
import DishDetailModal from "./dishDetailModal";

class RestaurantMenu extends Component{


    renderDishes = (dishes)=>{
        console.log(dishes);
        return dishes.map((item,index)=>{
            console.log(item);
            {
                if (item.isAvailable === true) {
                    return (
                        <div key={index} className="dishContainer">
                            <button className="dishButton" onClick={()=><DishDetailModal/>}>
                                <text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{item.name}</text>
                                <br/>
                                <text>{item.discription}</text>
                                <br/>
                                <text>{item.price} €</text>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    )
                }else{
                    return(
                        <div key={index} className="dishContainer">
                                <text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{item.dishTitle}</text>
                                <br/>
                                <text>{item.dishDescription}</text>
                                <br/>
                                <text>{item.dishPrice} €</text>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            }
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
                <br/>
                <div className="backButtonClass">
                    <button
                        className="backButton"
                        onClick={this.props.showMenuFunction}
                    >
                        <IoMdArrowBack size={40}/>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <br/>
                {this.renderDishes(this.props.requestedData[this.props.restaurantId].dishes)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In the renderDishes-function I want to render return all the dishes and wrap each in a button that opens the modal with specific dish-information. My problem is that the modal doesn't show up onClick. Here is the modal-component:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

export default class DishDetailModal extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            show: true
        }
    }

    handleModal = () =>{
        this.setState({show: !this.state.show})
    };



    render(){
        return (
            <>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={()=>this.handleModal}>
                    Launch demo modal
                </Button>

                <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={()=>this.handleModal}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={()=>this.handleModal}>
                            Close
                        </Button>
                        <Button variant="primary" onClick={()=>this.handleModal}>
                            Save Changes
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add a log to the `handleModal` function to see if the click event is triggered

Comment: I checked. It's not triggered.

Comment: @VincBue Could you please check my answer and let me know if it solves your issue?